# How can I find ID and class in a wordpress theme and replace with own text

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am working on a wordpress theme but need to amend some text filed such as place holder texts and some other fields name need to be amended. Unfortunately, I cannot find where they are exists in the theme. Please need help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your question you are probably not building a theme from scratch therefore I would suggest you follow the instructions for building a child theme and as you make your changes a more detailed question may be pertinent to the message board

https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Good Luck

Comment: Dear Chop62,

Thank you for your kind reply and suggestion. This is to inform you I just need few fields to change, do not need to change or customise whole theme. I am using a theme named, houzez where some fields are properties, agent and agencies. Apart from these there is a search bar which contains a text field along with some drop-down such as countries, city, property type, property status. Now I wish to make some changes as I am making a website for Educational Constant agencies where will be many universities and their courses by countries.

Comment: You still need to start with making a child of the  houzez theme and you can make whatever changes you want without worrying about core updates so much as you will see in the themes documentation most modifications will be made in functions.php but I highly recommend doing so with a child theme as if something goes wrong you can recover.